# Rename active excel workbook and sheet in python

Tags: xlwings

Is it possible in python to rename an active workbook and sheet?
I currently am using the xlwings "view" command to open my data frame up in excel which is nice but would like to have the active workbook/sheet named without saving it to a specified directory.

```
import xlwings as xw
xw.view(df)
```

When I try overriding the fullname of the active workbook I get an attribution error

```
xw.books.active.fullname = "Report"
```

> AttributeError: can't set attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rename the active Sheet in active Workbook you can try:

```
xw.books.active.sheets.active.name = "test"
```